# I am not able to connect to Oracle XE database in another system?

Tags: oracle

I have used this code to connect to XE database:

```
        OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = "data source=XE;user id=hr;password=sdmo1365";
        con.Open();
        OracleCommand com = new OracleCommand();
        com.CommandText = "select * from regions;";
        com.Connection = con;
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Load(com.ExecuteReader());
        con.Close();
        grd.DataSource = dt;
        grd.DataBind();
```

it is working in one pc while not working in another and giving this error:
**oracleexception was unhandled by user code** 
the only difference in tnsnames.ora of those pc is in the one that is not working the host is longer(becuase the user is under domain:)
(HOST = MOSININI-9.novini.mms.sti)
is this making the problem?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

I simply reinstalled it and everything get solved!(I waste 2 hours)